# import error for installed python package numpy and scipy, but scikit-learn works fine

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, pip

I installed scikit-learn, numpy and scipy packages on my Windows 8 system. I use Python 3.5
When I try importing sklearn, it works fine but Importerror occurs for numpy and scipy. Further, though sklearn import is success, I am not able to import a particular module from it.Please see the code snippet below:

```
C:\Users\CAN U VISH>python
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec 6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit       (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'scipy'
>>> import sklearn
Import Success
>>> from sklearn import datasets
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'datasets'
>>>
```

P.S. I had installed numpy and scipy using miniconda as pip installation failed

Comment: just try to install using `pip35 install xxx`. Or use virtualenv.

Comment: If possible, you could also try to install [Ananconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) which comes with a bunch of packages and makes managing them quite easy.